# What instruments do the members of Houkago Tea Time use?

Tags: k-on

The instruments in K-On have labels with real music companies. For instance, here's Ritsu's yellow drum set (I'm not quite sure where this picture is from, or even if it's just fanart, but the drums are clearly the same as those in the anime):

[image]

That's a very clear Yamaha logo. Either Yamaha sponsored it, in which case they'd want a real product to be used, or the artist chose to use that particular model, but either way it's very likely a real-world instrument.

What models are their instruments? As a note, I think a couple of them might have multiple instruments, since I've seen Ritsu with a different drum set also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-on), which cites specific episodes as references:

Yui: Heritage Cherry Sunburst Gibson Les Paul Standard electric guitar

Mio: Left-handed, 3-Color Sunburst Fender Jazz Bass with a tortoiseshell pickguard with  D'Addario EXL160M medium bass strings; in the first volume of the manga, Fender Precision Bass

Mugi: Korg Triton Extreme 76-key keyboard; in the first season's ending animation, Korg RK-100 keytar; in the second season's ending animation, Hammond organ

Ritsu: Yellow Rick Marotta Signature Yamaha Hipgig drum kit with a cymbal set from Avedis Zildjian; in the ending animation, white Yamaha Absolute Series drumkit

Azusa: Fender Mustang electric guitar

Comment: The HTT seiyuu actually used this instruments live during a live concert of K-on! which was really cool.